# Changing the location of the postgreSQL file

Tags: sql, postgresql, debian

I am installing postgreSQL on my debian server using apt-get. The postgresql.conf is located here:

```
/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf
```

Is there a way to actually change where postgreSQL looks for this config without my having to install postgreSQL by building it from source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the location of the .conf file when you start PostgreSQL.

[From the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-file-locations.html):

> *If you wish, you can specify the configuration file names and locations individually using the parameters config_file, hba_file and/or ident_file. config_file can only be specified on the postgres command line*

Where `config_file refers` to the location of the postgresql.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `do_ctl_all()` function in `/usr/share/postgresql-common/init.d-functions` and see how it tries to locate the postgresql instance to start at boot:

```
for c in /etc/postgresql/"$2"/*; do
    [ -e "$c/postgresql.conf" ] || continue
    name=$(basename "$c")

    # evaluate start.conf
    if [ -e "$c/start.conf" ]; then
    ....
```

This code shows that despite the fact that the path to `postgresql.conf` is not hardcoded (the version number and cluster name are variables), the way is it built by concatenating the different parts is hardcoded.

You may still symlink `postgresql.conf` manually to somewhere else, though I'm not sure how an automatic upgrade of the package would cope with that.